# Unnumbered back cover + blank page before chapter

Tags: covers

I'm trying to achieve a rather simple thing: a double-sided document with the back of the cover blank + a blank page before each new chapter. I've got this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
%\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%    
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\fancypagestyle{blank}{%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
        \fancyhead[LO,RE]{}}        
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
   \hbox{}
   \thispagestyle{blank}
   \newpage
   \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
  \huge Test
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

I need

```
\fancypagestyle{blank}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{}}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
   \hbox{}
   \thispagestyle{blank}
   \newpage
   \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

to create the blank page before the chapter. But if I use this, the back of my cover is numbered (2). In other words, thispagestyle{empty} is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, what you want is almost the default of [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class `scrbook`:

```
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses,headsepline]{scrbook}
\let\MakeMarkcase\MakeUppercase
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}% I would replace the center environment by \centering command

\begin{center}
  \huge Test
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter% AFAIK this should be before \begin{titlepage} because the title pages of a book usually are counted (but do not show a number).
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Test2}

\lipsum[10-18]

\chapter{Test3}

\lipsum[20-26]

\end{document}
```

[image: five pages of output with KOMA-Script]

To make the page number bold, you can additionally use

```
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
```

and to not print the running head slanted and additional

```
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
```

would be needed.

To use the chapter title for the running head of both, odd and even pages, you can additionally use [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage):

```
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses,headsepline]{scrbook}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\usepackage[markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}% I would replace the center environment by \centering command
  \huge Test
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Test2}

\lipsum[10-18]

\chapter{Test3}

\lipsum[20-26]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you to you both. Your solutions are indeed working. Discovering KOMA-Script, I think it's gonna get me a neater preamble. I'll dig into the documentation to adapt my titlesec settings.

Answer (score 4):

With the **emptypage** package, you could achieve your goal. If empty, even pages before a new chapter are really blank. And the back of your cover is also completely blank. No need of your *blank* fancypagestyle, neither the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

I hope I have correctly understand your question (As in this code, chapter 2 ends on page 6, chapter 3 directly begins on page 7, and not on page 9 nor page 8. But as usual, chapter 1 ends on page 3, and chapter 2 begins on page 5, not on an even page).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%    
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}


\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
  \huge Test
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Test2}

\lipsum[10-18]

\chapter{Test3}

\lipsum[20-26]

\end{document}
```